# Blender UI bleeding through and refresh is messed up

Tags: interface

who do I report this too? whenever I mouse over it the UI goes bonkers, redraws previous states of being or the desktop bleeds through. If I change the lay out it will show parts of the previous one when I move the mouse over it.

[image]
default showing with video editing being selected.

[image]
Default just bleeds though showing desktop and part of UI.

Comment: This feels more like an OS refresh/redraw issue, I see some penguins, and I'm guessing you run mint or similar, and I also realize this is usually a MS  answer but have you tried rebooting? Gnome/KDE/x/etc.. can get messed up too.

Comment: humm let me try killing them penguins - this is slack with fluxbox I am running. btw fyi - that didn't work. MS ?? too this is the only app that this does this with, OS refresh would effect everything all UI's yes?

Comment: Hmm, did it used to work and just recently starting doing this?  Have you tried (are you on)  latest stable build of blender?